# Land meaning end up in prison

Tags: grammar

Looking at Wiktionary, which sense is used when we say one ***landed*** in prison? ***Landed*** in a hospital?

- (intransitive) To descend to a surface, especially from the air.
- (dated) To alight, to descend from a vehicle.
- (intransitive) To come into rest.
- (intransitive) To arrive at land, especially a shore, or a dock, from a body of water.
- (transitive) To bring to land.
- (transitive) To acquire; to secure.
- (transitive) To deliver.

Comment: I suppose it's a metaphorical use of (1) or (3).

Answer (score 5):

It's being used as in your third entry: to come to rest, or to "wind up".

At age 24, after years of skirting the law, John Doe finally landed in prison.

Especially this definition, from **[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/landed)**:

> **[land](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/landed)**
>
> intransitive verb
>
> 2 a : to come to the end of a course or to a stage in a journey : arrive
>    *took a wrong turn and landed on a dead-end street*
>
> 2 b : to come to be in a condition or situation
>   *landed in jail*